# Cakephp 3 forms, insert into FOREIGN KEY

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Here is are my cods:

```
<?= $this->Form->create('Posts', array('url' => array('controller' => 'MyController', 'action' => 'index')));?>
                        <?= $this->Form->input('title', array('type'=>'title','class'=>'form-control mr-sm-2'));?>
                        <?= $this->Form->textarea('text', array('type'=>'text','rows' => '3','class'=>'form-control'));?>
                        <?= $this->Form->submit('Posten', array('class'=>'btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0','style'=>'float:right'));?>
                    <?= $this->Form->end();?>
```

And here is my Controller:

```
 $post = $this->Posts->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $post = $this->Posts->patchEntity($post, $this->request->getData());
        debug($post);
        if ($this->Posts->save($post)) {

        $this->Flash->success(__('You have posted something.'));
        }


        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('Error, plase check your'));
    }
```

The Problem is the Problem:

```
INSERT INTO posts (title, text) VALUES (:c0, :c1);
```

But i need :

```
INSERT INTO posts (title, text,user_id,picture_id) VALUES (a,b,$user_id,$picture_id);
```

The Preoblem is that i need to insert it in Controller not in view. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `$user_id` and `$picture_id` are variables that have been declared in your controller function, and have been properly checked for security if they are coming from user input (e.g. if they're in the URL, you've confirmed that they are okay and not just trusted them because the URLs that you give people links to are always valid), then the following should work:

```
$post = $this->Posts->patchEntity($post,
    array_merge($this->request->getData(), compact('user_id', 'picture_id'))
);
```

Comment: it doesn't work .  And where should i put the variable $user_id and $picture_id?

Comment: You don't already have those variables? It's hard to tell, you haven't included the whole function. And you said that you wanted them to be saved in the record. So I assumed they already existed. You'll need to provide more details.